# Erro inexistente de ECHO? unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Tags: php

Olá, já olhei várias vezes de cima a baixo cada letra, não consigo entender por que ele dá o  erro:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) 
>   in C:\wamp64\www\registrar.php on line 15

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
?>

<?php
$jogador=$_POST['jogador'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];
$senhaConfirma=$_POST['senhaConfirma'];
$jogador=strip_tags($jogador);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email=strip_tags($email);

if($email == "")
(
echo "Você não digitou um email";
echo "<br><A href='cadastro.php'>Voltar</a>";
exit;
)
if($senha==$senhaConfirma)
(
$umJogador="SELECT * from jogadores where usuario='$jogador'";
$umJogadorDois=mysql_query($umJogador) or die("Não foi possivel encontrar a tabela de jogadores.");
$umJogadorTres=mysql_fetch_array($umJogadorDois);
)
if(!$_POST['senha'] !! $_POST['senhaConfirma'])
(
printf "A confirmação da senha está errada";
echo "<a href='cadastro.php'>Voltar</a><br>";
exit;
)
else if($umJogadorTres || strlen($jogador)>21 || strlen($jogador)<1)
(
printf "Já existe um jogador com o mesmo nome de usuário que você, ou você deixou o campo em branco, ou excedeu o número de caractéres.";
echo "<a href='cadastro.php'>Voltar</a><br>";
exit;
)
else
(
$umEmail="SELECT * from jogadores where email='$email'";
$umEmailDois=mysql_query($umEmail) or die("Não foi possivel encontrar a tabela de senhas.");
$umEmailTres=mysql_fetch_array($umEmailDois);
)
if(!$umEmail)
(
printf "Já existe um jogador com o mesmo endereço de email";
echo "<a href='cadastro.php'>Voltar</a><br>";
exit;
)
else
(
$senha=md5($senha);

$SQL = "INSERT into jogadores(usuario, email, level, exp, senha) VALUES('$jogador', '$email', '1', '0', '$senha')";
mysql_query($SQL) or die("Não foi possivel cadastrar.");

print "Obrigado por cadastrar!";
)

else
(
print "A sua senha não é igual a confirmação da senha ou você não digitou nenhuma senha";
echo "<a href='cadastro.php'>Voltar</a><br>";
exit;
)
echo " <a href='login.php'>Página de login</a><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Para delimitar um bloco de código use `{` e não `(` no `if($email == "")(` e no resto.

Comment: Ah, e uma dica... deixe seu código identado, com espaços em branco (3 normalmente) nos blocos de instruções dentro dos "if´s". Fica melhor para ler e editar posteriormente o código quando for necessário.

Answer (score 3):

A sintaxe correta do `if` é:

```
if(condição)
{

    //código

}
```

E não com parenteses `()` como está na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

ifs usam `()` pra condição e não pra "declaração":

Errado:

```
if(CONDICAO)
(
    declaração
)
```

Correto:

```
if(CONDICAO)
{
    declaração
}
```

Eu realmente não sei aonde esta aprendendo PHP (Não se ofenda), mas recomendo que estudo o básico do PHP:

- Estrutura: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php